# Decorate class that has no self in method signature in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-decorators

I am trying to apply decorator dynamically to classes.
It works if I have a class method including self in method signature.

**Working example:**

```
from functools import wraps

def debug(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('awesome')
        f = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return f
    return wrapper

def debugclass(cls):
    # cls is a class
    for key, val in vars(cls).items():
        if callable(val):
            setattr(cls, key, debug(val))
    return cls

class Dude:
    def test(self):
    #def test(): # this does not work
        pass

debugclass(Dude)
dude = Dude()
dude.test()
```

**How could I change Dude class method signature so that it would work without self being part of signature?**

```
class Dude:
    def test(): # without self
        pass
debugclass(Dude)
dude = Dude()
dude.test()
```

**Getting error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "withoutself.py", line 33, in <module>
dude.test()
File "withoutself.py", line 7, in wrapper
f = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: test() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `test()` method to be callable without a `self` or `cls` parameter you need to make it a `staticmethod`.

```
class Dude:
    @staticmethod
    def test():
        pass
```

Then you also need to update `debugclass` to wrap `staticmethod` objects as they aren't callables. Unfortunately you'll need a different way to wrap the staticmethod objects:

```
def debugclass(cls):
    # cls is a class
    for key, val in vars(cls).items():
        if callable(val):
            setattr(cls, key, debug(val))
        elif isinstance(val, staticmethod):
            setattr(cls, key, staticmethod(debug(val.__func__)))
    return cls

>>> class Dude:
    def test(self):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def test1():
        pass


>>> debugclass(Dude)
<class __main__.Dude at 0x7ff731842f58>
>>> Dude().test()
awesome
>>> Dude.test1()
awesome
```

Comment: Thanks! Well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, you can't.
Elaboratedely, python passes object instance as a first argument when a method is called. Therefore if you define a method with no arguments you get the execption. The 1 given argument is your "dude" object.

For more information please see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects